# How can I do split-toning black & white in SilverEfex Pro?

Tags: software, black-and-white, nik-software, split-tone

Using Nik Software Silver Efex Pro 2 and Lighroom 4

How do I tone different areas of photo in beige, dark, lighter shades of grey and black and mustard shades.

Comment: What you are looking for is a split-toning effect.

Comment: I don't think you can easily do this. The control points in the software give you some, but not all, of the control you're looking for, but without having the ability to do layers and mask, it's pretty challenging to do more than the split-toning that everyone is mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a straightforward workflow for split-toning, but if you want to get some very delicate split toning in Silver Efex, try under "Finishing Details" changing the Paper Tone and Silver Tone.

As @Francesco said, there is a perfectly good split toning adjustment in Lightroom proper.

Answer (score -1):

In lightroom (both 3 and 4) you have the Split Tone feature in the develop module, which allows you to choose hue and saturation both for highlights and shadows (and to decide where each one of them begins).

Here it is a quick example, where I simply converted to B&W and applied the parameters shown. The shot was hand-held :-)

[image: A quick example]

Comment: She does mention Nik's Silver Efex as part of this workflow, so split toning in LR doesn't answer the question really.

Comment: I have seen. She also mention LR4, though.

Comment: Yes, but a key part is Silver Efex. It's a pretty powerful package for B&W and it's external to LR (it's a plugin, but runs outside).